# Water Mark on Image - intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/Commands/Argument.php on line 41

Tags: image, laravel-5, watermark

How to solve this error, I'm trying to add watermark on the image but getting below errors:

libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile libpng warning: iCCP: cHRM chunk does not match sRGB [Mon Oct 1 15:06:36 2018] PHP Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in /var/www/newProject/vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/Commands/Argument.php on line 41

Comment: Solved It, By running this command "pngcrush -d out -rem alla test_watermark.png"

Comment: http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/ Assuming you want pretty much nothing besides the raw image data / transparency data too:

Comment: I would like to suggest you use http://image.intervention.io/ this library. this is efficient and much easy to use.
I am using the same for my site https://penit.ink and it's quite awesome.

Comment: I solved it, Thanks all for the help